# How to get name of button when clicked - tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to get the name of a button when pressed. I have looked at several other answers, but I don't understand how to get them to work. This is what I have:

```
number = 0
location = 0
characters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
text_list = []
for idx in characters:
    text_list.append(Button(window, text=characters[number], command = clear))
    text_list[-1].place(x=location, y=0)
    location += 18
    number += 1
```

it makes a button for every letter in the alphabet (I am making hang man). The unstyled result looks like this:
[image]

I now want a way to get the name of the button, so that I know what letter was pressed. That is what I need help on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using:

```py
import tkinter as tk
import string # string.ascii_lowercase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"


def button_pressed(button):
    # `button.cget("text")` gets text attribute of the button
    print("Button text =", button.cget("text"))


text_list = []
window = tk.Tk()

# Iterate over each letter in the alphabet
for character in string.ascii_lowercase:
    # Create the button
    button = tk.Button(window, text=character)
    # Add the command attribute to the button
    button.config(command=lambda button=button: button_pressed(button))
    # Show the button on the screen using `.pack` because it's much easier to use
    button.pack(side="left")
    # Append it to the list of buttons
    text_list.append(button)

window.mainloop()
```

It passes the `button` to the function which uses `button.cget("text")` to get the text from the button.

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much for spending your time to solve my problem. It is much appreciated

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to get the name of a button when pressed.

Easier way to do without `list`, `append` and `config`.

Snippet:

```
import tkinter as tk
import string  # Can be ignored, just used to generate the list of keys

root = tk.Tk()

class Keyboard:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        # Can be ignored, just used to generate the list of keys
        self.keys = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase]

        for i in range(0, 26):
            self.master.columnconfigure(i, weight=1)
            self.button = tk.Button(self.master, text=self.keys[i], command = lambda name=self.keys[i]:self.click_one(name))
            self.button.grid(column=i, row=0, sticky='EW')

    def click_one(self, name):
        self.keys = name
        return print(self.keys)           

keyboard = Keyboard(root)

root.mainloop()
```